# Git: Setting up simple Push

Tags: git

I have used git many times but never had to set one up myself. I am having trouble wrapping my brain around getting it set up on the server. I have been following [Git: Setting Up the Server](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-on-the-Server-Setting-Up-the-Server).

I have my repo.git placed in ../opt/git/ on the server, ran 'git --bare init'. I have an SSH account created just for the use of this git repo.

I have this in my local config file:

```
[remote "origin"]
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:ref/remotes/origin/*
    url = https://<mysshuse>:<mypass>@https://website.com/opt/git/reponame.git
```

But I get a `fatal: repo not found`

I wasn't sure if the git. at the start of the url a custom subdomain you set up or what, so I added it and got.

```
fatal: unable to access: Could not resolve host: git.reponame.com
```

Can I not just use my SSH login? Is it better (more secure) to create the SSH keys instead? I don't quite understand having to make a SSH Key. I thought this step could be skipped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `url` is wrong, for ssh:

```
url = ssh://user[:pass]@host[:port]path/to/dir.git/
```

So that would be

```
url = ssh://yoursshuser:yoursshpass@website.com/opt/git/zcarddepot.git/
```

That said, you shouldn't put a password in there. You could use a ssh agent to forward the key to the client so you don't have to log in.

---

Solution:
`/~/` worked since I have this outside my web root. So the correct URL would be...

```
url = ssh://yoursshuser:yoursshpass@website.com/~/opt/git/zcarddepot.git/
```

Comment: Changed. Getting a new permissions error but I should have access to it. 

`fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.`

Comment: Checked the access with this ssh user I'm trying to use.

`drwxrwsr-x 7 zcardepo zcardepo 4096 Jul 25 16:44 zcardepot.git/`

Comment: @tdm Is your ssh user `zcardepo`? If not, you don't have write permissions.

Comment: @Leeft Added, still the same error. I tried using an ip address for <website.com> just to try it.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Correct, I'm using that ssh user. I thought drwxrwsr-x 7 is a the correct permissions to be set for the git? Am I wrong?

Comment: It doesn't even really need the `s`: `drwxrwxr-x  8 myuser mygroup 4096 Feb 15 15:49 myrepo.git` works fine for me

Comment: if your repo is before the public folder of your domain then you should add this symbol before the url: ~